# Does the iPhone has AJAX and jQuery support?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax, mobile-safari

Does the iPhone has AJAX and jQuery support?

I am developing a chatbox for iPhone with these two.

Are they supported on MobileSafari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are.. for jQuery there is even special plugin at http://www.jqtouch.com/

If you are developing on a pc or on linux you might want to download the [Palm WebOS emulator](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1788) the browser on the iPhone and the Palm WebOS devices are extremly simular due to the way the browser is built (webkit). The default resolution (Palm Pre mode) should be the same as the iPhone :)

Comment: i have an ipod touch myself, this is a question because i tried it out but something has failed. Just trying to know if there is a good support to mention that is not the problem. So it is not.

Comment: and btw; i can use Safari, to let it work just the same. (not the resolution; but that doesnt matter

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've used them both recently for a project.